# Stream data from Webcaster to Icecast

Tags: node.js, icecast, internet-radio

So i'm using the [Webcaster Browser Client](https://github.com/webcast/webcaster) and I also got the [Webcast NodeJS example server](https://github.com/webcast/webcast.js) working locally as well. I'm receiving the data from the client in the server e.g

> Mon Jul 16 2018 14:31:11 GMT+0300 (FLE Daylight Time) -- Got 1252 bytes of binary data

But I've been googling for a couple of days and can't seem to find information on how to actually pass those chunks of data to my Icecast server.

Additional Info that might be relevant: Icecast server : 2.4.3; Platform: Windows; Server is not running the liquidsoap example, it's the NodeJS one

Can someone point me in a direction or provide some sample code? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've posted solution in comments.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so I've somehow managed to resolve my problem. Posting solution for any future reference if anyone needs help. Save this as `script.liq`:

```
# Log dir
set("log.file.path","./tmp/basic-radio.log")

# Serveur settings
set("harbor.bind_addr","0.0.0.0")

# An emergency file
emergency = single("./file.ogg")

# A playlist
playlist = playlist(mode="randomize",reload=60,"./music")

# A live source
livedj = input.harbor(
       "mount",
       port=8080,
       password="hackme"
)

# fallback
radio = fallback(track_sensitive=false,
                 [livedj,playlist,emergency])

# Stream it out
output.icecast(
    %mp3,
    host = "localhost",
    mount = "stream",
    user = "source",
    public = true,
    port = 8000, password = "hackme",
    genre = "Surprise",
    name = "DemoStream",
    radio)
```

Install Liquidsoap and run `liquidsoap script.liq`.

This configuration uses the default settings for an Icecast server so you only need to start up the Webcaster client and stream to `ws://source:hackme@localhost:8080/mount`. Cheers!